# Injections and bijections on sets $\{1,2,3\}^\omega$ and $\{4,5\}^\omega$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

## Problem

(Source: "Mathematics for Computer Science", Lehman, Leighton, Meyers, 2018.)

> The set $\{1,2,3\}^\omega$ consists of the **infinite** sequence of the digits 1, 2 and 3, and likewise $\{4,5\}^\omega$ is the set of infinite sequences of the digits 4, 5.
>
> (a) Give an example of a total injective function $f:\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\rightarrow \{4,5\}^\omega$
>
> (b) Give an example of a bijection $g:(\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega)\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}^\omega$
>
> (c) Explain why there is a bijection between $\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega$ and $\{4,5\}^\omega$.

## Solution attempt

(a) I will define a function $f$ that constructs a sequence of 4, 5 as follows: Starting from the beginning of the input string, it reads the input 3 digits at a time, and transforms each 3-digit sequence into a 5-digit sequence of 4, 5 using the following mapping: all 27 possible 3-digit sequences of 1, 2, 3 in increasing order (i.e., $111, 112, 113, 121, 122, \cdots, 332, 333$) are respectively mapped to the 27 first 5-digit sequences of 4, 5 in increasing order ($44444, 44445, 44454, 44455, 44454, 44455, \cdots, 55445, 55454$).

In other words, the mapping from the 3-digit sequences to the 5-digit sequences is: $111\rightarrow 44444, 112\rightarrow 44445, 113\rightarrow 44454, 121\rightarrow 44455, \cdots, 332\rightarrow 55445$, $333\rightarrow 55454$.

For example, $f(113333\cdots)=4445455454\cdots$.

$f$ is a total injection:

1. $f$ is total, because the above construction can be applied to any sequence in $\{1,2,3\}^\omega$ to obtain a result that is in $\{4,5\}^\omega$.
2. $f$ is injective, because, given an infinite sequence in $\{4,5\}^\omega$ that consists of 5-digit sequences $44444,\cdots,55454$, it can be mapped to only one sequence in $\{1,2,3\}^\omega$ by replacing each 5-digit sequence of 4, 5 back with a 3-digit sequence of 1, 2, 3.

(b) Let $(s,t)$ be an element of $\{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$.

I will define a function $g$ that transforms $(s,t)$ into a sequence $u \in \{1,2,3\}^\omega$ using the following mapping:

Let $s_i$ be $i$-th digit of $s$, and let $t_i$ be $i$-th digit of $t$. For each $i\ge 0$, make $u_{2i} = s_i$ and $u_{2i+1} = t_i$. In other words, each pair of digits $(s_i,t_i)$ from $(s,t)$ will add a 2-digit sequence $s_it_i$ to $u$. For example, if $s_0=1$ and $t_0=2$, $u_0u_1=12$; and, if $s_1=1$ and $t_1=1$, $u_2u_3=11$.

$g$ is a bijection because:

1. It is total: for all $(s,t)\in \{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$, a sequence $u \in \{1,2,3\}^\omega$ can be constructed using the above mapping.
2. It is injective: for all $u \in \{1,2,3\}^\omega$, the above mapping can be applied in reverse order to obtain a single $(s,t)\in \{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$. That is, for any given $u = u_1u_2u_3u_4\cdots$, an $(s,t)$ can be constructed by doing $s=u_0 u_2 u_4 u_6\cdots$ and $t=u_1 u_3 u_5 u_7\cdots$.
3. It is surjective: every single $u \in \{1,2,3\}^\omega$ can be obtained by applying $g$ to every $(s,t)\in \{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$. This is true because, as $(s,t)$ ranges over all pairs of sequences, the operation of taking the digit pair $(s_i,t_i)$ will produce all possible pairs of 1, 2, 3: $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$. So, this will produce all possible 2-digit sequences $s_it_i$. Since $u$ is formed by concatenating infinitely many 2-digit sequences $s_it_i$, $g$ will produce all possible infinite sequences $u\in \{1,2,3\}^\omega$.

(c) This one is where I am stuck. I can't seem to figure out why there is a bijection from $\{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$ to $\{4,5\}^\omega$. More specifically, I can't seem to be able to find a way to map from $\{1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{1,2,3\}^\omega$ to $\{4,5\}^\omega$ that is surjective. Does anybody have any hint as to how to proceed with this one?

Can someone please check my solution attempt?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was an answer to this post where the answerer gave a hint for item (c). He suggested that I apply the Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show that the required bijection exists. However, now that I came back to this post, I saw that the answer is gone for some reason.

In any case, here is an attempt to apply the Schröder-Bernstein theorem to item (c).

The Schröder-Bernstein theorem states that, for any two sets $A,B$, if there is a total injection $f_1:A\rightarrow B$ and a total injection $f_2:B\rightarrow A$, then there is a bijection $f_3:A\rightarrow B$.

So, if we find a total injective function $f_1:(\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega) \rightarrow \{4,5\}^\omega$ and a total injective function $f_2:\{4,5\}^\omega\rightarrow(\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega)$, then it will follow that there is a bijection between $\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega$ and $\{4,5\}^\omega$.

1. To find $f_1$:

   From items (a) and (b), there is an injective function $f:\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\rightarrow \{4,5\}^\omega$ and a bijection $g:(\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega)\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}^\omega$.

   Note that, since $g$ is a bijection, then it is also a total injection.

   So, define $f_1 := f\circ g$. The function $f_1$ is a total injection, because the composition of two total injective functions is a total injective function.
2. To find $f_2$:

   I'll first define a total injection $h:\{ 4,5\}^\omega\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}^\omega$. Define $h(x)$ as a function that replaces, in $x$, every occurrence of $4$ with $1$ and every occurrence of $5$ with $2$.

   Now, $f_2$ can be defined as $f_2(x)=(h(x),h(x))$.

   $f_2$ is total, because it can be applied to any $x \in \{ 4,5\}^\omega$. $f_2$ is injective, because, for any two $x,y \in \{ 4,5\}^\omega$, if $x \neq y$, then the strings produced by $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ will be necessarily different, so $f_2(x)$ and $f_2(y)$ will be different.

Therefore, by the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, it follows that there is a bijection between $\{ 1,2,3\}^\omega\times \{ 1,2,3\}^\omega$ and $\{4,5\}^\omega$.